# Override method but parameter is arg0

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i use eclipse auto Override a method:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas arg0, MapView arg1, boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}
```

you see ,the parameter is arg0,arg1,arg2,it is hard  to read.i think if my eclipse is have mistake, because i think it should give me :

```
draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean flag)
```

so my question why my eclipse give me arg0 and so on,how to solve it?

Comment: Eclipse will provide argument's like that only, you have to change what you want..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you install "Documentation for Android SDK" via "Android SDK Manager" it will be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirely on the fact whether or not Eclipse has the **sources** of the third party code **available on the build path** of that project. In your case it only has the binary class file, and can only provide you with the types, as argument names are not part of the binary anymore.

That said, please

- install the sources of your Android target
- have Maven download the
  sources of artifacts you use in Maven
- attach sources to third party
  libraries that you use
- install the SDK versions of Eclipse plugins that you
  use as target platform

to solve this issue in different environments.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. That's Eclipse way of naming variables. But it is recommended to change them to proper names.

> *Side Note*: To rename a variable in your code using Eclipse: `Right click on the variable => Refactor => Rename`

Comment: It's clear this is compilable, but horrible code.  Refactor-rename on every variable created this way would be ludicrous.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't makes any difference. But Its always a good practice to write the code in such a way so that it should be self explanatory.

Imp is the "type" and no. of passing parameters in the method, They should be correct and Which i guess is.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't matter what the name of the parameter is. Just make sure that you pass the correct variable / parameter value.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot agree here. The name shall reflect the meaning. If you ever happen to work together with other people in a team, they will not be happy about first "decoding" the names in your code.

Comment: We're all professionals here, and suggesting this is *legal* is obvious -- and clearly not a tolerable solution.